# Exceptional file handling

Tags: c++, exception

I am new to c++ and i was trying to implement exceptional file handling using c++.
In the following code i inherited the **class Divide_By_Zero_Exception** from the base **class exception**.After running the code i am getting error

> error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
>   {

Why do i need to specify class name if i am inheriting it publicly.And if i need to specify it how to do it.

```
//program to throw an exception if denominator is zero
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
class Divide_By_Zero_Exception : public exception
{
public:
    const char * what() const throw() {
        return "Divide By Zero Exception";
    }
};
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Divide_By_Zero_Exception d;
    int n1, n2;
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    try
    {
        if (n2 == 0)
            throw d;
        else
            cout << n1 / n2;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Please edit your question to include a comment in the code where the error is.

Comment: Nit pick, but this question has nothing to do with file handling, just handling exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `std::exception` not `exception` because your `using`-directive isn't effective yet when you use the name.

Also, instead of

```
const char * what() const throw()
```

you probably wanted to write

```
const char * what() const noexcept
```

Comment: Perhaps also explain why it is `std::` in this case?

Comment: @thomas_f I did.